# How can i remove white space from background image?

Tags: html, css

I have added owl carousel and i have added background images for slider images. But it shows white space in right side for each background images for all browser. I have tried this code below:

```
<div class="main_slider">

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

<div class="item active ad1">

    <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h2> <span>Lucayan</span> is the best  Onepage Travel template </h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et  dolore magna incididunt ut labore aliqua. </p>       </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>                             

 <div class="item ad2">

   <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h2><span>Responsive </span> Designs  Onepage Travel template</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et  dolore magna incididunt ut labore aliqua. </p>





                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</div> <!-- This is End of item ad2 -->

  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main_slider .item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover;
} 
.owl-carousel .item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;   
    background-size: cover;  
  -o-background-size: cover;

}

.ad1{
  display: block;
  height: 600px;
  background:  url('../img/img1.jpg') no-repeat  fixed; 
 }

.ad2{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 550x;
 background:  url('../img/img2.png') no-repeat ;
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

I have given width 100% but still can't figure it out.  How can i remove it?!

This is [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82a78ha0/2)

Comment: show us either relevant code (HTML too) or a fiddle.

Comment: use FireBug or similar browser tools to establish all the CSS rule influences to each page element.

Comment: Try to add the whole code with HTML on JSFiddle - it's much more easier to answer then ;-)

Comment: I don't think owl carousel uses background images - doesn't it just use image tags?

Comment: The "cover" option center the image and resize to make sure you see all of it. Make sure your Width and Height are the same as your element.

Comment: @pete as usual owl carousel has image tags but it works for background images as i have added button and text in images that's why i have used background images.